# Crawling: Extract all text and links(href and ng-href) from AngularJs website and Crawl

Tags: angularjs, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

After a lot of struggle trying to crawl an angular Js page with Single sign-on I have put up this code. This code runs fine, logins opens the desired page and scraps it but I am not getting all the links and text present in the website loaded by angular. My xpath seems to be correct.

Also it is not crawling the links that are getting extracted. What do I need to change in my code to extract all text present in the website and the subsequent webpages?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import TextResponse 
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from ps_crawler.items import PsCrawlerItem
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class SISSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "SIS"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://domain.com/login?"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        # selenium part of the job
        self.driver.get("https://domain.com/login?")
        time.sleep(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Login"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input').send_keys("ssasdad")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Login"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[2]/input').send_keys("")
        #self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]').click()

        more_btn = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login"]'))
                )
        time.sleep(5)
        more_btn.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.driver.execute_script("window.open('https://domain.com/#/admin','_blank');");
        time.sleep(10)
        window_now = self.driver.window_handles[1]
        self.driver.switch_to_window(window_now)
          ## stop when we reach the desired page
            #if self.driver.current_url.endswith('page=20'):
            #   break

         #now scrapy should do the job
        time.sleep(10)
        response = TextResponse(url=self.driver.current_url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
        time.sleep(10)
        for post in response.xpath('//div'):
            item = PsCrawlerItem()
            print post.xpath('a/span/text()').extract(), post.xpath('a/@href').extract(),  post.xpath('a/@ng-href').extract()
```

Comment: Do you know how many links will be there on the page beforehand?

Comment: No. I am just extracting everything what is present. But when I do inspect elements I observe a significant amount of text and links are left out.

Comment: You would most likely need to wait before getting the `page_source` and passing it to Scrapy. But, the question is - wait for what? Is there any indication that the page has completed loading?

Comment: I have already given a sleep time of 10 before passing the page source and when chrome opens the window. The page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to tweak your xpath a little bit as follows. Hope this solves the problem.

```
for post in response.xpath('//body'):
    print post.xpath('//text()').extract(), post.xpath('//a//@href').extract()
```